# In web Api 2 RDLC report controller why can't i return to FILE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

what i am trying to do is to generate a PDF/Excel report in mvc web API 2 and view in a new tab in a browser.

My error says 'Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method'.

did i miss a namespace or a assembly?

any help is much appreciated.

Here is My code:

''' 
public IHttpActionResult TestReport()
        {

```
        var fromDate = "01/01/2000";
        var toDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var id = "PDF";

        var result = new ApiResult();

        var lr = new LocalReport();

        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Test.rdlc");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Status = ApiResult.ApiStatus.Error;
            result.Message = "Report Error";

            return Ok(result);
        }


        if (fromDate == "" && toDate == "")
        {
            fromDate = "01/01/2000";
            toDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }

        var from = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
        var to = Convert.ToDateTime(toDate);


      var Staffs = db.Staffs.Where(s =>
             DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.EffectiveDate) >= from.Date
              && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.EffectiveDate) <= to.Date && s.IsActive == true).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
          .ToList();

        var Staffs = db.Staffs.Where(s => s.empId == "10001").OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).ToList();

        var Items = Staffs.Select(item => new DepViewModel
        {
            empId = item.empId,
            Name = item.Name,
            IdCard = item.IdCard,
            })
            .ToList();

        var param0 = new ReportParameter("fromdate", from.ToShortDateString());
        var param1 = new ReportParameter("todate", to.ToShortDateString());

        lr.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { param0, param1 });


        var ds = new ReportDataSource("DepDataSet1", Items.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id));


        lr.DataSources.Add(ds);

        string reportType = id;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;



        string deviceInfo =

            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;



        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    } '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileContentResult is MVC Action Result. You don't File (FileContentResult) in WebAPI.

Please modify your last return statement(`return File(renderedBytes, mimeType)`) as follows:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(renderedBytes)
};
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType); //"application/pdf"
var input = $"inline; filename={fileNameExtension}"; //where fileNameExtension something with file name and extension for e.g., myfilename.txt
ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(input, out contentDisposition))
{
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
}

return this.ResponseMessage(result);
```

Comment: Work like a charm..Thank you so much :)